# nextjs configure to avoid http server timeout

Tags: next.js

I've a nextjs project proxied by nginx. I'm consuming a rest api served by nextjs itself that takes more than 2 minutes.

First error I get was 504 timeout by nginx so I added some additional directives:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Then the error code becomes 502. Looking at proxy_error_log file the error is

```
 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream.
```

In my project I'm not using express or any other server explicitly so I don't know how to set http server timeout. Any way to set timeout from next.config.js file or globally for node js?

Comment: Any update maybe? If you found the solution, can you please answer you own question and I upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from [secret104278](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11920#discussioncomment-106683):*

...this issue only occur in node12 but not in node14. This because default timeout in node12 is 2 minutes and there is no timeout in node14

The only way to get around this in next.js with node12 is using `--http-server-default-timeout` by something like `NODE_OPTIONS='--http-server-default-timeout=0' next start`

Hope this help anyone